# Returning List From Customer Method Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I wanted to return List from custom function but im getting error def

```
myFunc (credit : Column)  = {for ( i <- 0 to col("credit")) yield  i}
```

Calling custom function

```
.withColumn("History" , explode (myFunc("credit")))
```

> Error message "Expected column but found Seq"

I want to explode it to split into multiple rows.

Comment: You should use udf function for that

Comment: So UDF will be a Scala code right? Can I use sql functions like "col" ext?